# React Not Found rendering server side

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I use **React Router v4** and this works well.

```
<Switch>
    <Router path="/users/:uid" component={Profile} />
    <Router path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Okay, if I access the domain `/blabla` **NotFound** component renders well.

---

But I wonder how can I render **NotFound** to `/users/:uid` when user is not exist.

```
app.get('/users/:uid', (req, res) {
    if( // user exist) { 
        res.json({user})
    } 

    else res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not exist'})
})
```

Perhaps I need to hook up server response, but I don't know what is best way.

```
class Profile extends Component {

   componentWillMount = () => {
       this.props.fetchUser(uid)
   }

   render(){

       if(!this.props.loading && !this.props.user) return <NotFound />
       else return (...)
   }
}
```

Is this correct way? I'm using redux together.

Comment: This is totally fine in my humble opinion

Comment: @KyawSiesein Is this? Yes I applied code like this, and it works !

Comment: Yes. it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Profile extends Component {
   render(){
       if(!this.props.loading && !this.props.user) {
        this.props.history.push('/bababa') // you can jump to notFound
        return
      }
       else return (...)
   }
 }
```

is this?

Comment: Not offensive, just routing back to the route which didn't exist is just dumb.

Comment: So this is jump and jump again. You are creative man!, But I won't use this way